# Pivot Table with absolute values and percentages in columns with values in rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, pivot-table

I want to have a table with values

```
    A   B   C
--+-------------
1 | x   a   1
2 | x   b   0
3 | y   a   1
4 | x   b   1
5 | y   a   1
```

and want to have the following Pivot Table

```
Filter A: x

            a           b           total
--------+-----------------------------
        |   #   %       #   %       #   %
--------+-----------------------------
count B |   1   -       2   -       3   -  
sum C   |   1   100%    1   50%     2   67%
```

where `count B` is count of A='x' and B appropriate
and `sum C` is the sum of column C where A='x' and B appropriate.
The percentages in the rows are the `sum C` value of that rows divided by the count of rows with A='x' and appropate B.

So I was able to figure out how get just the absolute values. I found solutions where I can add the percentages as an additional row value but not column. Is this possible somehow?

And how can I calculate the percentages? Or should I open another question?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to add a calculated column to your underlying table that gives the correct result.  You can then add that column to your pivot table.

Comment: it is not possible since the percentages are calculated depending on the current filter and values of the column A and B. The values there are not fixed in their amount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i created two blocks one with absolute values calculated by the pivot table. The second one are the percentages which are calculated by formulas from the pivot table.